# Is it possible to translate an arbitrary attribute grammar into an attribute grammar that uses only synthesized attributes?

Tags: compiler-construction

Is it possible to translate an arbitrary attribute grammar into an attribute grammar that uses only synthesized attributes? You can assume that the computation for evaluating an attribute can be arbitrarily complex.

My understanding says its not possible because Inherited attributes allow capturing information from the context (parent nodes) in the parse tree, which is crucial for defining the semantics of certain constructs

Comment: This is not a programming question and would probably be a better fit over on the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site.